# Fotos não se alinham

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um app para absorver conhecimento e acabei com uma coisa meia estranha, é o seguinte a função do app é abrir uma lista de fotos (parseia uma xml, pega umas fotos da pasta assets) e aí quando ele vai amostrar a lista de fotos ele não fica um do lado do outro.

[Classes](https://goo.gl/Kyb8LK)

Comment: Davi, sempre adicione o código na pergunta, linkar ele em varios outros links, e ainda em site externo não é recomendavel no site, e ainda dificulta quem for te ajudar. leia [É uma boa idéia colocar o código no Pastebin ao invés de colocar o código na pergunta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4255/28595)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta colocar dentro de um `LinearLayout(horizontal)`, e verifica se o seu `xml` está `LinearLayout` ou `RelativeLayout`. Recomendo que user o `RelativeLayout` pois consegue trabalhar melhor.

Comment: Funcionou! obrigado!